# How can I print the second to last line of many files into one file?

Tags: sed, awk, tail, busybox, head

I have many CSV files in one directory which have various lengths.  I'd like to put the second to last line of each file into one file.  I tried something like `tail -2 * | head -1 > file.txt`, then realized why that doesn't work.

I'm using BusyBox v1.19.4.

Edit: I do see the similarity with some other questions, but this is different because it's about reading multiple files.  The `for` loop in Tom Hunt's answer is what I needed and hadn't thought of before.

Comment: Pretty clearly not a duplicate, since question mentions the solution to that issue as a failed attempt.

Comment: @TomHunt yes, I'm sure that is why [mikeserv has reposted his answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237268/6761)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for i in *; do tail -2 "$i" | head -1; done >>file.txt
```

That should be `sh` (and hence Busybox) compatible, but I don't have a non-bash available for testing ATM.

Edited in accord with helpful comments.

Comment: Good (+1) but better would be: `for i in *; do tail -2 "$i" | head -1; done >>file.txt`.  Because of the double-quotes, this works even if file names contain whitespace.  It is also slightly more efficient since `file.txt` only gets open and closed once.

Comment: I'd suggest quoting the variable, to protect against unexpected filenames - `for i in *; do tail -2 "$i" | head -1; done >file.txt`

Comment: That works wonderfully on Busybox.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

With a GNU or BSD `sed`:

```
sed -s 'x;$!d' -- files... >outfile
```

...for example:

```
for   i in        10 50 100 1000
do    seq "$i"   >file"$i"
done
sed -s 'x;$!d' -- file[15]0*
```

---

```
9
99
999
49
```

You can do it with `tail`, too:

```
tail -n2 file[15]0* | sed -ne'n;p;n;n'
```

---

```
9
99
999
49
```

...but you need to be *sure* that there are at least two lines in each infile, because in that case `sed` isn't `-s`eparating any streams, and a one-off will affect the rest of the output. But `tail` definitely isn't going to print any *more* than the last two lines in each file, and it will follow each set of those with a blank line, and lead each set with its spec'd filename header *(which could cause problems if there are newlines in the filenames, actually)*.

This is what `tail` prints:

```
tail -n2 file[15]0*
```

---

```
==> file10 <==
9
10

==> file100 <==
99
100

==> file1000 <==
999
1000

==> file50 <==
49
50
```

...which, if you haven't any better option, isn't really all that hard of a stream to handle.

And thinking about it, if there *are* less than two lines in a file, the `sed` solution will output a blank line for that file. If you would prefer it wrote nothing at all for that file:

```
sed -s 'x;$!d;1d' -- file[15]0*
```

...would do the trick.

---

The `tail | sed` command does work with only `busybox` builtins, though, unfortunately, `busybox sed` does *not* handle the `-s`eparate streams option. At least, my build doesn't:

```
busybox sed --help
```

---

```
BusyBox v1.21.1 (2013-07-28 11:02:27 EDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: sed [-inr] [-f FILE]... [-e CMD]... [FILE]...
or: sed [-inr] CMD [FILE]...
```

Also frustratingly, [`toybox sed`](http://landley.net/toybox/) *(which I much prefer, and which is officially included on android systems)* falsely reports that it *does* support the option in its `--help` output, and then refuses to recognize it elsewhere:

```
toybox sed -s -e 'x;$!d' -- file[15]0*
```

---

```
usage: sed [-inrE] [-e SCRIPT]...|SCRIPT [-f SCRIPT_FILE]... [FILE...]

Stream editor. Apply one or more editing SCRIPTs to each line of input
(from FILE or stdin) producing output (by default to stdout).

-e  add SCRIPT to list
-f  add contents of SCRIPT_FILE to list
-i  Edit each file in place.
-n  No default output. (Use the p command to output matched lines.)
-r  Use extended regular expression syntax.
-E  Alias for -r.
-s  Treat input files separately (implied by -i)

...

sed: Unknown option s
```

dammit.